# Is the UID on mifare classic read only?

Tags: mifare

Are UID read only on mifare Classic cards? (I mean in normal cards, not UID changeable mifare cards)

I thought it was not possible but this document states that it can be changed http://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.2285.pdf :

> Consequences of our attack Any system using mifare Classic cards that relies
>   on the secrecy or the authenticity of the information stored on sector zero is now
>   insecure. Our attack recovers, in a few minutes, all secret information in that sector.
>   It also allows us to modify any information stored there

Is that true?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security aspects of MIFARE Classic. It may belong to http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

UID is readable only on all MIFARE cards according the [official FAQ](http://www.mifare.net/en/micommunity/qa/).

> Can I assign my own UID to MIFARE Cards?
>
> UIDs for MIFARE cards are assigned during the production and it can
>   never be changed thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the card manufacturer. Because with Classic Mifare cards with read-only UID came also so called "magic" cards which have rewritable block 0 where is also stored card UID. To write block 0 you have to usually send "backdoor" sequence to the card, which opens block 0 for writing.

Here are examples of such cards:
http://www.proxmark.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=6545